# Scanner.scan / initializing variables

Tags: java

I'm having a simple little problem, I need to have the variable "age" be read from the scanner.scan, where the user inputs a number. It keeps telling me to initialize it, but in order to do that I need to provide the variable with a set whole number, which I don't want to do. How could I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*; 

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person

{

    public static void main(String[]args) 

    {

    int age;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter in your age.");

     if (age < 18) 

     {
         System.out.println("Youth is a beautiful thing.");
     } 

     else

     {
        System.out.println("Age is just a state of mind.");
     }


}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must read in the `age`. See below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Person
{
   public static void main(String[]args) 
   {
      int age;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter in your age.");
      age = scan.nextInt(); <---- **//This is what you are missing**

      if (age < 18) 
      {
         System.out.println("Youth is a beautiful thing.");
      } 

      else
      {
         System.out.println("Age is just a state of mind.");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

under System.out.println("Enter in your age.");

```
    age = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not reading `age` anywhere. To do that do the following after initializing scan.

```
age = scan.nextInt();
```